# ebay Trading API Call "GetItemTransactions" results mismatch

Tags: ebay-api, trading

I have got a small question. It would be very kind of anyone who can answer this.

Ok, when I go to the Purchase History page of a ebay product via the website. Say for eg:-

http://offer.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewBidsLogin&_trksid=p2047675.l2564&rt=nc&item=160907756849

I can clearly see that it shows that total 365 items have been sold and the list shows the last 100 transactions which is great.

Ebay Trading API call "GetItemTransactions" Link is
http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/GetItemTransactions.html

However,  when I make the ebay trading api call "GetItemTransactions" to get the same, I just get back 50 transactions and not the last 100 like the website. I am getting the total items sold number 365 correctly. I am only sending the required fields

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<GetItemTransactionsRequest xmlns='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents'>
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>My Ebay Auth Token...</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <ItemID>160907756849</ItemID> 
    <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
</GetItemTransactionsRequest>
```

and getting back this

```
<PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfPages>1</TotalNumberOfPages>
    <TotalNumberOfEntries>50</TotalNumberOfEntries>
</PaginationResult>
<HasMoreTransactions>false</HasMoreTransactions>
<TransactionsPerPage>100</TransactionsPerPage>
<PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
<ReturnedTransactionCountActual>50</ReturnedTransactionCountActual>
```

As the Result shows I only get 50 transaction objects in the element "TransactionArray" as "ReturnedTransactionCountActual" is showing 50 and the "HasMoreTransactions" shows as false, meaning there are no more transactions beyond this i.e 50 clearly indicating a mismatch between the api results and the website results.

Why doesnt the api give back the last "100" transactions like the website and only giving back "50". Am I missing something or is this a bug??

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

My two cents says that some of these order happened more then 30 days ago. Look at [ModTimeFrom](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/GetItemTransactions.html#Request.ModTimeFrom). (Just looked at link, You Date Range is from **Jun-21-13 09:59:20 PDT** to **Apr-17-13 19:25:26 PDT**. Clearly more then 30 days)

> If you don't specify a ModTimeFrom/ModTimeTo filter, the NumberOfDays
>   time filter is used and it defaults to 30 (days).

You have not set either, **NumberOfDays** or **ModTimeFrom/ModTimeTo**. Thus the call defaults to 30 days. I'm guessing that on the Ebay Site the date filter is much larger / not applied.